# Двойной цвет у контура

Tags: android, android-studio

Есть текстовая строка с одноцветным контуром

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать что бы контур имел два цвета(низ и верх были белыми, а левая и правая сторона красными)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="#ECECEC" />
        <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#FFF"/>
</shape>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Так должно сработать:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:left="-2dp" android:right="-2dp">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#ECECEC" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dip"
                android:color="#FFFFFF" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:top="-2dp" android:bottom="-2dp">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#ECECEC" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dip"
                android:color="#FF0000" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Суть в том, чтобы сделать 2 прямоугольника, а их стороны вынести за пределы отрисовки.